# How to save pictures made in the Mathematica Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am working in the Mathematica Cloud and generate some pictures.

Is there a way to save them, e.g. as pdf-files, on my computer in order to insert them in documents?

I only manage to save the notebook but not the pictures only.

Comment: You can CloudExport and follow the url to download it. Or access it via cloud's file manager

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get the picture without the bracket { ...} for out= and the comma between array elements?

Comment: Try `GraphicsColumn`, `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsGrid`. If they don't work, please show a concrete example.